# Is there a most efficient way to multiply three matrices A * B * C = D using cuBLAS?

Tags: cuda, matrix-multiplication, cublas

I want to find the most efficient way to multiple three matrices using cuBLAS. My current solution has the obvious multiple calls to cublasgemm

```
cublas<t>gemm(cublasH, transa, transb, m, n, k, &alpha, d_A, lda, d_B, ldb, &beta, d_AB, ldc)
cublas<t>gemm(cublasH, transb, transc, m, n, k, &alpha, d_AB, ldab, d_C, ldc, &beta, d_D, ldd)
```

It's not a my opinion that this a *bad* solution. Only that it would be *better* were there some way to do with a single kernel/function call rather than 2, as a single kernel would presumably get a bit more speed up.

I've looked at [cublasgemmBatched](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cublas/index.html#cublas-t-gemmbatched) hoping there were some manipulation to be made, but it's stated that the multiplications must be independent from each other, so that seems off the table.

Is there some way to use cuBLAS or some other mathematical shortcut worth trying to achieve this optimization?

Comment: I am not aware of *any* BLAS incarnation with a special API for multiplying three matrices. Generally speaking, when multiplying more than two matrices, the order of the matrix multiplies can make a significant difference to performance, especially when matrices with high aspect ratios (e.g. "skinny") are involved. See also [matrix chain multiplication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_chain_multiplication)

Answer (score 3):

CUBLAS doesn't have any direct support for this (a single function call that accepts 3 matrices to be multiplied together.)

The way to do it in CUBLAS is the way you have already indicated.